# Check to make sure only one inspector is open

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm writing an VSTO Outlook Addin and I open up my own inspector (form) to have the user put in information.  How can I check to make sure an instance of the form isn't loaded before opening another?

Comment: How are you opening your own inspector? Is this a replacement/custom form region or just a custom Window?

Comment: Can you make your custom window modal? You could just use a single window - using a class-level variable, and if it's already open -  don't open it again.